# Javascript. Convert datetime to pretty date. Strange format

Tags: javascript, datetime

How can I, using Javascript, convert the below data to pretty format, i.e. "2 days ago"?

2011-08-11 16:12:31.119218+0000

What is this format called?

Thankful for all input!

Comment: If you're asking what your input format is called, it's [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 6):

I think that format is called "fuzzy time". Here's a good jquery library for that: http://timeago.yarp.com/. And here's one that doesn't require jquery, but will use it if it's available: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

Comment: eJohn does not seem to support it. How can I convert this format to something better?

Comment: How does the ejohn library not support it? It's right there at the top of the page: `prettyDate("2008-01-26T22:24:17Z") // => "2 days ago"`

Comment: Actually I think I misunderstood your original post. You are looking for converting exactly the format in "2011-08-11 16:12:31.119218+0000" to a fuzzy date. I thought you had a date object that you could export in any format, in which case you could import that into the fuzzy date method.

Comment: You can use `new Date("2011-08-11 16:12:31.119218+0000")` to turn it into a javascript Date object. Then you can export using `Date.format()` into a format that one of these libraries supports.

Comment: Never mind solved it. But I do not know what format that is best. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you need to convert your time to a format that prettyDate can use. i.e. "2008-01-28T20:24:17Z". Then you can pass the result into prettyDate.

Comment: What is this format called : 2008-01-28T20:24:17Z how can I convert to  it?

Comment: Johnathan, your questions are starting to get beyond the domain of a stackoverflow question. I'd recommend reading a good tutorial on javascript dates.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/zachleat/Humane-Dates

```
/*
 * Javascript Humane Dates
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Dean Landolt (deanlandolt.com)
 * Re-write by Zach Leatherman (zachleat.com)
 *
 * Adopted from the John Resig's pretty.js
 * at http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date
 * and henrah's proposed modification
 * at http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/#comment-297458
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 */

function humaneDate(date, compareTo){

    if(!date) {
        return;
    }

    var lang = {
            ago: 'Ago',
            from: '',
            now: 'Just Now',
            minute: 'Minute',
            minutes: 'Minutes',
            hour: 'Hour',
            hours: 'Hours',
            day: 'Day',
            days: 'Days',
            week: 'Week',
            weeks: 'Weeks',
            month: 'Month',
            months: 'Months',
            year: 'Year',
            years: 'Years'
        },
        formats = [
            [60, lang.now],
            [3600, lang.minute, lang.minutes, 60], // 60 minutes, 1 minute
            [86400, lang.hour, lang.hours, 3600], // 24 hours, 1 hour
            [604800, lang.day, lang.days, 86400], // 7 days, 1 day
            [2628000, lang.week, lang.weeks, 604800], // ~1 month, 1 week
            [31536000, lang.month, lang.months, 2628000], // 1 year, ~1 month
            [Infinity, lang.year, lang.years, 31536000] // Infinity, 1 year
        ],
        isString = typeof date == 'string',
        date = isString ?
                    new Date(('' + date).replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")) :
                    date,
        compareTo = compareTo || new Date,
        seconds = (compareTo - date +
                        (compareTo.getTimezoneOffset() -
                            // if we received a GMT time from a string, doesn't include time zone bias
                            // if we got a date object, the time zone is built in, we need to remove it.
                            (isString ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset())
                        ) * 60000
                    ) / 1000,
        token;

    if(seconds < 0) {
        seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
        token = lang.from ? ' ' + lang.from : '';
    } else {
        token = lang.ago ? ' ' + lang.ago : '';
    }

    /*
     * 0 seconds && < 60 seconds        Now
     * 60 seconds                       1 Minute
     * > 60 seconds && < 60 minutes     X Minutes
     * 60 minutes                       1 Hour
     * > 60 minutes && < 24 hours       X Hours
     * 24 hours                         1 Day
     * > 24 hours && < 7 days           X Days
     * 7 days                           1 Week
     * > 7 days && < ~ 1 Month          X Weeks
     * ~ 1 Month                        1 Month
     * > ~ 1 Month && < 1 Year          X Months
     * 1 Year                           1 Year
     * > 1 Year                         X Years
     *
     * Single units are +10%. 1 Year shows first at 1 Year + 10%
     */

    function normalize(val, single)
    {
        var margin = 0.1;
        if(val >= single && val <= single * (1+margin)) {
            return single;
        }
        return val;
    }

    for(var i = 0, format = formats[0]; formats[i]; format = formats[++i]) {
        if(seconds < format[0]) {
            if(i === 0) {
                // Now
                return format[1];
            }

            var val = Math.ceil(normalize(seconds, format[3]) / (format[3]));
            return val +
                    ' ' +
                    (val != 1 ? format[2] : format[1]) +
                    (i > 0 ? token : '');
        }
    }
};

if(typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    jQuery.fn.humaneDates = function(options)
    {
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            'lowercase': false
        }, options);

        return this.each(function()
        {
            var $t = jQuery(this),
                date = $t.attr('datetime') || $t.attr('title');

            date = humaneDate(date);

            if(date && settings['lowercase']) {
                date = date.toLowerCase();
            }

            if(date && $t.html() != date) {
                // don't modify the dom if we don't have to
                $t.html(date);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To produce "2 days ago" use [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) which returns the time in milliseconds since January 01, 1970 according to universal time.

The following is an example on how to return a pretty date based on date differences for dates less than a week, otherwise, it returns [Date.prototype.toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString):

```
function prettyDate(date, startDate) {
  var secs = Math.floor((date.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000);
  if (secs < 60) return secs + " sec(s) ago";
  if (secs < 3600) return Math.floor(secs / 60) + " min(s) ago";
  if (secs < 86400) return Math.floor(secs / 3600) + " hour(s) ago";
  if (secs < 604800) return Math.floor(secs / 86400) + " day(s) ago";
  return date.toDateString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at javascripts date object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.  You can set this into a date object and create another date object to compare to.

Comment: [Here's a better reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Please don't feed W3Schools (see why [here](http://w3fools.com/))

Answer (score 0):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is pretty handy for these types of data formatting issues.